# Creating mysql table with user variables via php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table with variables introduced by the user. If I "echo" the final variable it shows that the line is correct however I still can not create it. Can someone help me?

```
<?php

$ligacao=mysql_connect('localhost','root','')
or die ('Problems connecting to MySQL');
$dbname = $_POST['txt_db_name'];
$tbname = $_POST['txt_tb_name'];
$campo1 = $_POST['txt_campo1'];
$campo2 = $_POST['txt_campo2'];
$campo3 = $_POST['txt_campo3'];
$campo4 = $_POST['txt_campo4'];
$campo5 = $_POST['txt_campo5'];
$campo6 = $_POST['txt_campo6'];
$campo7 = $_POST['txt_campo7'];

mysql_select_db($dbname,$ligacao);




$query = "CREATE TABLE ".$tbname." ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ".$campo1."VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, ".$campo2." VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ".$campo3." VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, ".$campo4." VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, ".$campo5." VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, ".$campo6." VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, ".$campo7." VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))";

echo $query;

$resultado = mysql_query($query,$ligacao);


mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: **Immediately** stop using this code. It is vulnerable to SQL injection and uses `mysql_*` functions which are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: What does mysql_error(); give you?

Comment: that is the problem. Php gives no error it just doesn't create the table. But it should work or am i wrong?

Comment: what does the `echo $query;` give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need a space before the first "VARCHAR(20)

Comment: I have corrected it however it still does not work

Comment: What does echo $query show?